# MS WORD: How to get the height occupied by a line of text in a specific font and font size?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I have encountered a typesetting problem that requires a format of 20pt Times New Roman font with  one blank line above and below the text. I want to format it as a style, but to do this I need to calculate the font height in a line to adjust line spacing.

I read the following from "Microsoft Word Secrets The Why and How of Getting Word to Do What You Want" by Flavio Morgado,

> Line spacing = 1 is typographically defined as 120% the size of the greatest
> font used in a single line. Or more specifically, it calculates 20% of the height between the
> Ascender and Descender lines for current text line and uses this space to separate it from
> the previous text line of text

but the book doesn't tell how tall a text in a specific font and size.

I used to guess that 20pt means 20pt high, but the hypothesis is false since if I change the font then the line spacing changed, so for a specific size, different fonts may occupy different height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in your analysis that Word treats fonts in a funny
and unexplained manner.

The article
[Fonts, point size and line spacing](http://practicalseries.com/1001-webdevelopment/03-02-grid.html)
has analyzed the question in depth and came up with the conclusion
that empirically measuring the distances is the only method.

This is an example from the article of how different fonts work :

[image]

Line-spacing is defined as the distance between the baselines of two
consecutive lines. As seen above, this is a property of the font
and not of the chosen point-size.

Answer : In Word, unlike most text-editors, you can't *calculate* the
line-height of a font, but you rather have to *measure* it.

The author of the article has finally just chosen the line-spacing
figure by his personal taste, by trying various settings until he
found the one that he liked the best.

(Read the article, it makes for interesting reading, even if a bit
frustrating.)